# Best way to export data from a GWT app?

Tags: php, gwt

I have written a scientific GWT application that basically just asks for parameters, performs the calculation and then plots the result (numeric data is not presented). It works just fine.

Now a user asked me for a way to "export" the data (1000 double-precision numbers). How should I do this? I think:

a) The most elegant way would be an "Export data" button that would open a "Save as..." dialog. If I have understood correctly, this cannot be done, for security reasons, on client side. But I cannot run a Java servlet on the server, and the data set is too large to give in URL for a PHP script.

b) A button that copies the data to clipboard would probably be the next best thing. But it seems that GWT doesn't currently implement this, and a cross-browser solution would be complicated in JSNI. Should something fail, the user would have no access to data.

c) A button to open a PopUpPanel or a new window that would display the numeric data. Last resort. Should be implemented in a way that would allow the "Select all" to select only the data.

Any thoughts? Can anyone think of ways to avoid c)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can `POST` the data to a PHP script. You don't have to pass it in the URL. You can post data to any server side script using the [FormPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.html) class.

There is an example on the JavaDoc page, but it would go something like this:

```
FormPanel form = new FormPanel();
form.setAction("/yourPhpScript.php");
form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);

Hidden postData = new Hidden();
postData.setName("dataset");
postData.setValue( /* your data set */ );

form.add(postData);


form.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler() {
  public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
    // When the form submission is successfully completed, this event is
    // fired. Assuming the service returned a response of type text/html,
    // we can get the result text here (see the FormPanel documentation for
    // further explanation).

    // So what you want to return from your PHP script is a link to a URL of the exported results
    Window.alert(event.getResults());
  }
});

RootPanel.get().add(form);
```